# Help solving an integral in hydrodynamics

Tags: integration

I am currently taking a course on hydrodynamics and was halted by a tricky integral. $ \mu \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} ( r  \frac{\partial W}{\partial r}) = \beta$.

I want to integrate this so that the speed W is on its own. Which rules do I have to use? Thanks for the help!

Comment: With Mathematica code:`DSolve[μ*1/r*D[r*W'[r], r] == β, W[r], r][[1]]`. I have:$W(r)=\frac{r^2 \beta }{4 \mu }+c_2+c_1 \ln (r)$

Comment: Do you know how to do it by hand?